# System database Log backup and recovery model

Tags: sql-server, system-databases

I am very new to sql server, does anyone know what kind of recovery model for each system databases. I don't know if I should all make it to simple or full in my databases. Because if the database is in full so I need to create a log backup for that.

Comment: Recovery model is dependent on your environment.  Check Technet for details on what each level means, then you'll have to decide for yourself.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189275.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's basically an option between simple and full. Which one to use depends on your requirement on what data can be lost in case of a disaster and to what point in time you can restore back to.

In simple recovery model you can only restore up to the latest backup and the only point in time you can restore into is the end time of the backup. If that is not enough, you need to use full. Then you can restore back to any point in time.

The third option is bulk logged, which is basically full with the exception that bulk load operations can be done with minimal logging and you can lose the changes done in the bulk load if the disaster happens before it ended.